# Query to calculate the proportion

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am new to SQL (using SQLiteStudio) and I wrote such a query to calculate Proportion for each group ( number of rooms) from the total sale of apartments. But it doesn't calculate correctly. Give a result of 100 for each group.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong  can you guys help in any way? Thanks!

```
    1. SELECT 
    2.l.num_rooms as "Number",
    3.count(l.id_locale) as "Number sales",
    4.round(count (l.id_locale)/
    5.(SELECT count (l.type_locale)FROM locale 
    6.WHERE l.type_locale = 'Appartement' )*100,2) as "Proportion"
    7.FROM locale l
    8.WHERE l.type_locale = 'Appartement' 
    9.GROUP BY l.num_rooms
    10.ORDER BY l.num_rooms;
```

| type_locale | surface | num_rooms | fk_lieu | id_locale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Appartement | 52 | 1 | 45 | 1 |
| Appartement | 45 | 2 | 67 | 21 |
| Appartement | 12 | 3 | 34 | 78 |
| Appartement | 67 | 2 | 89 | 12 |
| Appartement | 31 | 1 | 15 | 56 |

Comment: Please provide sample data as text. Under circumstances both count could be equal.

Comment: I provided sample data

Answer (score -1):

I see two problems in your code: 1) You are using and integer division (2/5 = 0); 2) the subquery is a correlated one while it should be unrelated to a main query. So use another alias in the subquery and convert at least one of the arguments in the expression to real.

```
SELECT  l.num_rooms as "Number",
    count(l.id_locale) as "Number sales",
    round(count(l.id_locale)*1.0 /
       (SELECT count(l2.id_locale) FROM locale l2
        WHERE l2.type_locale = 'Appartement' )*100,2) as "Proportion"
FROM locale l
WHERE l.type_locale = 'Appartement' 
GROUP BY l.num_rooms
ORDER BY l.num_rooms;
```

Comment: I downvoted because you opened a duplicate closed question just to post the answer that is already there in the duplicate link.

Comment: My bad. closing

Comment: @forpas, Sorry, couldn't find the dublicate link with both two problems. Would you please point me in a right direction?

Comment: There are 2 problems here: 1) integer division which is covered by the duplicate link and a typo: missing alias l after FROM locale in the subquery. In any case the question should be closed. Note that the OP has already asked the same question again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70939235/query-to-calculate-the-proportion which was closed and they deleted it.